# Zeta-function regularization of determinants and traces

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, linear-algebra, analytic-number-theory, regularization

The short answer to my question may be a pointer to the right text.  I will give all the background I know, and then ask my questions in list form.

Let *A* be an operator (on an infinite-dimensional vector space).  You might as well assume that its spectrum is all real and positive.  In fact, I only care when the spectrum is discrete and grows polynomially, but I hear that this stuff works more generally.

In general, *A* is not trace-class (the sum of the eigenvalues converges) or determinant-class (the product of the eigenvalues converges) — if the *n*th eigenvalue grows as *n*<sup>*p*</sup> for some *p*>0, then it won't be.  But there is a procedure to try to define a "trace" and "determinant" of *A* nevertheless.

Let us hope that for large enough *s*, the operators *A<sup>-s</sup>* (=exp(-*s* log *A*), and log *A* makes sense if the spectrum of *A* is positive) are trace-class.  If so, then we can define ζ<sub>*A*</sub>(*s*) = tr(*A<sup>-s</sup>*); it is analytic for Re(*s*) large enough.  Let's hope that it has a single-valued meromorphic continuation and that this function (which I will also call ζ<sub>*A*</sub>(*s*)) is smooth near *s*=0 and *s*=-1.  All these hopes hold when the eigenvalues of *A* grow polynomially, whence ζ<sub>*A*</sub>(*s*) can be compared to the Riemann zeta function.

Then we can immediately define the "regularized trace" TR *A* = ζ<sub>*A*</sub>(0) and the "regularized determinant" DET *A* = exp(-ζ<sub>*A*</sub>'(0)), where by ζ<sub>*A*</sub>'(*s*) I mean the derivative of ζ<sub>*A*</sub>(*s*) with respect to *s*.  (If the eigenvalues λ<sub>*n*</sub> are discrete, then ζ<sub>*A*</sub>(*s*) = Σ λ<sub>*n*</sub><sup>-*s*</sup>, and so one would have TR *A* = Σ λ<sub>*n*</sub> and DET *A* = Σ (log λ<sub>*n*</sub>) λ<sub>*n*</sub><sup>-*s*</sup> |<sub>*s*=0</sub>,  if they converged.)  If *A* is trace- (determinant-) class, then TR *A* = tr *A* (DET *A* = det *A*).

So, here are my questions:

1. Is it true that exp TR *A* = DET exp *A*?
2. Let *A*(*t*) be a smooth family of operators (*t* is a real variable).  Is it true that d/d*t* [ log DET *A*(*t*) ] = TR( A<sup>-1</sup> d*A*/d*t* )?  (I can prove this when A<sup>-1</sup>d*A*/d*t* is trace-class.)
3. Is DET multiplicative, so that DET(*AB*) = DET *A* DET *B*?  (I can prove this using 1. and 2., or using the part of 2. that I can prove if *B* is determinant-class.)
4. Is TR cyclic, i.e. TR(*AB*) = TR(*BA*)?
5. Is TR linear, i.e. TR(*A* + *B*) = TR *A* + TR *B*?

None of these are even obvious to me when *A* and *B* (or d*A*/d*t*) are simultaneously diagonalizable (except of course cyclicity), but of course in general they won't commute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will answer some of my questions in the negative.

**3.**
First consider the case of rescaling an operator *A* by some (positive) number λ.  Then ζ<sub>λ*A*</sub>(s) = λ<sup>-s</sup>ζ<sub>*A*</sub>(s), and so TR λ*A* = λ TR *A*.  This is all well and good.  How does the determinant behave?  Define the "perceived dimension" DIM *A* to be log<sub>λ</sub>[ (DET λ*A*)/(DET *A*) ].  Then it's easy to see that DIM *A* = ζ<sub>*A*</sub>(0).  What this means is that DET λ*A* = λ<sup>ζ<sub>*A*</sub>(0)</sup> DET *A*.

This is all well and good if the perceived dimension of a vector space does not depend on *A*.  Unfortunately, it does.  For example, the Hurwitz zeta functions ζ(s,μ) = Σ<sub>0</sub><sup>∞</sup>(n+μ)<sup>-s</sup> (-μ not in **N**) naturally arise as the zeta functions of differential operators — e.g. as the operator *x*(d/d*x*) + μ on the space of (nice) functions on **R**.  One can look up the values of this function, e.g. in Elizalde, et al.  In particular, ζ(0,μ) = 1/2 - μ.  Thus, let *A* and *B* be two such operators, with ζ<sub>*A*</sub> = ζ(s,α) and ζ<sub>*B*</sub> = ζ(s,β).  For generic α and β, and provided *A* and *B* commute (e.g. for the suggested differential operators), then DET *AB* exists.  But if DET were multiplicative, then:

DET(λ*AB*) = DET(λA) DET(*B*) = λ<sup>1/2 - α</sup> DET A DET B

but a similar calculation would yield λ<sup>1/2 - β</sup> DET A DET B.

This proves that DET is not multiplicative.

**1.**
My negative answer to 1. is not quite as satisfying, but it's OK.  Consider an operator *A* (e.g. *x*(d/d*x*)+1) with eigenvalues 1,2,..., and so zeta function the Reimann function ζ(s).  Then TR *A* = ζ(-1) = -1/12.  On the other hand, exp *A* has eigenvalues e, e<sup>2</sup>, etc., and so zeta function ζ<sub>exp *A*</sub>(s) = Σ e<sup>-ns</sup> = e<sup>-s</sup>/(1 - e<sup>-s</sup>) = 1/(e<sup>s</sup>-1).  This has a pole at s=0, and so DET exp *A* = lim<sub>s→0</sub> e<sup>s</sup>/(e<sup>s</sup>-1)<sup>2</sup> = ∞.  So question 1. is hopeless in the sense that *A* might be zeta-function regularizable but exp *A* not.  I don't have a counterexample when all the zeta functions give finite values.

**5.**
As in my answer to 3. above, I will continue to consider the Hurwitz function ζ(*s,a*) = Σ<sub>*n*=0</sub><sup>∞</sup> (*n*+_a_)<sup>-*s*</sup>, which is the zeta function corresponding, for example, to the operator *x*(d/d*x*)+*a*, and we consider the case when *a* is not a nonpositive integer.  One can look up various special values of (the analytic continuation) of the Hurwitz function, e.g. ζ(-*m,a*) = -*B*<sub>*m*+1</sub>(*a*)/(*m*+1), where *B<sub>r</sub>* is the _r_th Bernoulli polynomial.

In particular,

TR(*x*(d/d*x*)+*a*) = -ζ(-1,*a*)/2 = -*a*<sup>2</sup>/2 + *a*/2 - 1/12

since, for example (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials)):

*B*<sub>2</sub>(*a*) = Σ<sub>*n*=0</sub><sup>2</sup> 1/(n+1) Σ<sub>*k*=0</sub> <sup>*n*</sup> (-1)<sup>*k*</sup> {n \choose k} (*a*+_k_)<sup>2</sup> = *a*<sup>2</sup> - *a* + 1/6

Thus, consider the operator 2_x_(d/d*x*)+*a*+_b_.  On the one hand:

TR(*x*(d/d*x*)+*a*) + TR(*x*(d/d*x*)+*b*) = -(*a*<sup>2</sup>+*b*<sup>2</sup>)/2 + (*a*+_b_)/2 - 1/6

On the other hand, TR is "linear" when it comes to multiplication by positive reals, and so:

TR(2_x_(d/d*x*)+*a*+_b_) = 2 TR(*x*(d/d*x*) + (*a*+_b_)/2) =  -(*a*<sup>2</sup>+2_ab_+*b*<sup>2</sup>)/4 + (*a*+_b_)/2 - 1/6

In particular, we have TR(*x*(d/d*x*)+*a*) + TR(*x*(d/d*x*)+*b*) = TR( *x*(d/d*x*)+*a* + *x*(d/d*x*)+*b* ) if and only if *a*=_b_; otherwise 2_ab_ < *a*<sup>2</sup>+*b*<sup>2</sup> is a strict inequality.

So the zeta-function regularized trace TR is not linear.

**0./2.**
My last comment is not so much to break number 2. above, but to suggest that it is limited in scope.  In particular, for an operator *A* on an infinite-dimensional vector space, it is impossible for *A<sup>-s</sup>* to be trace-class for *s* in an open neighborhood of 0, and so if the zeta-function regularized DET makes sense, then det doesn't.  (I.e. it's hopeless to say that det *A* = DET *A*.)  Indeed, if the series converges for *s*=0, then it must be a finite sum.

Similarly, it is impossible for *A* to be trace class and also for *A<sup>-s</sup>* to be trace class for large *s*.  If *A* is trace class, then its eigenvalues have finite sum, and in particular cluster near 0 (by the "divergence test" from freshman calculus).  But then the eigenvalues of *A*<sup>-*s*</sup> tend to ∞ for positive *s*.  I.e. it's hopeless to say that tr *A* = TR *A*.

My proof for 2. says the following.  Suppose that d*A*/d*t* *A*<sup>-1</sup> is trace class, and suppose that DET *A* makes sense as above.  Then

d/d*t* [ DET *A* ] = (DET *A*)(tr d*A*/d*t* *A*<sup>-1</sup>)

I have no idea what happens, or even how to attack the problem, when d*A*/d*t* *A*<sup>-1</sup> has a zeta-function-regularized trace.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a specialized knowledge about regularizations, but as the first direction I think:

<s>(1) yes, it's an identity if you look into definition of zeta-function</s> (I thought of a different definition of zeta-regulaization)

(2) not sure, I'll check later. But it seems to be an identity as well.

(4, 5) TR only depens on eigenvalues. I don't remember what the status of eigen{AB} = eigen{BA} is, but I think its true under standard conditions on A and B -- if they are self-conjugate in a Hilbert space.

Let's say you try to compare regularized `\det(1-AB)` and `\det(1-BA)`. I think the standard reasoning applies and says that those are equal; same might apply to `(A+B)`.

Comment: Great, although any chance you can either spell out the reasoning or point me to a reference?  For example, here's what I know about (1).  Let A have eigenvalues A_n.  Then DET exp A is: compute \sum A_n \exp(-s A_n), extend, and evaluate at s=0.  exp TR A is: compute \exp( \sum A_n^{-s}), extend, and evaluate at s=-1.  Is there a change of variables to get from one of these functions to the other?  Otherwise, I don't know why their extensions should match up.  But perhaps I'm being dumb.

Comment: I'll return to this on the weekend and see if I'm right :).

Comment: Ok, it's certainly my mistake --- I basically thought det exp A is defined as exp tr A which would make (1) trivial. But for the reference, I think http://books.google.com/books?id=PXkhYSqIeykC&pg=PA9&lpg=PA9&dq=zeta-regularization+trace+det&source=bl&ots=WwxiUJylKc&sig=J-ZjXUZefkn34bQzV3VXUmRSlWw&hl=en&ei=QknSSuezJp3J_gbUiYHZAg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CA0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=&f=false might help.